# How to calculate CPU % based on raw CPU ticks in SNMP

Tags: monitoring, nagios, snmp, central-processing-unit

According to http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/mibs/ucdavis.html#scalar_notcurrent `ssCpuUser`, `ssCpuSystem`, `ssCpuIdle`, etc are deprecated in favor of the raw variants (`ssCpuRawUser`, etc).

The former values (which don't cover things like nice, wait, kernel, interrupt, etc) returned a percentage value:

> The percentage of CPU time spent processing
>   user-level code, calculated over the last minute.
>
> This object has been deprecated in favour of
>   '`ssCpuRawUser(50)`', which can be used to calculate
>   the same metric, but over any desired time period.

The raw values return the "raw" number of ticks the CPU spent:

> The number of 'ticks' (typically 1/100s) spent
>   processing user-level code.
>
> On a multi-processor system, the '`ssCpuRaw*`'
>   counters are cumulative over all CPUs, so their
>   sum will typically be N*100 (for N processors).

My question is: how do you turn the number of ticks into percentage?

That is, how do you know how many ticks per second (it's *typically* — which implies not always — 1/100s, which either means 1 every 100 seconds or that a tick represents 1/100th of a second).

I imagine you also need to know how many CPUs there are *or* you need to fetch all the CPU values to add them all together. I can't seem to find a MIB that gives you an integer value for # of CPUs which makes the former route awkward. The latter route seems unreliable because some of the numbers overlap (*sometimes*). For example, `ssCpuRawWait` has the following warning:

> This object will not be implemented on hosts where
>   the underlying operating system does not measure
>   this particular CPU metric.  **This time may also be
>   included within the '`ssCpuRawSystem(52)`' counter.**

Some help would be appreciated. Everywhere seems to just say that % is deprecated because it can be derived, but I haven't found anywhere that shows the official standard way to perform this derivation.

The second component is that these "ticks" seem to be cumulative instead of over some time period. How do I sample values over some time period?

The ultimate information I want is: % of user, system, idle, nice (and ideally steal, though there doesn't seem to be a standard MIB for this) "currently" (over the last 1-60s would probably be sufficient, with a preference for smaller time spans).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these are absolute counters, you would have to regularly retrieve these
metrics and then do the calculation yourself. So, if you want the number over
the **next** minute, you would have to get the numbers, wait a minute, and get
the numbers again. SNMP would not update those numbers too often so you may
not be able to get these every second anyway.

Once you have the raw user, nice, system, idle, interrupts counters you can
get the total number of ticks by summing these up. Even the MIB description
says that adding them up is expected.

```
$ snmptranslate -Td .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.52
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawSystem
...
    This object may sometimes be implemented as the
    combination of the 'ssCpuRawWait(54)' and
    'ssCpuRawKernel(55)' counters, so care must be
    taken when summing the overall raw counters."
```

Then, regardless of how long it has been since you took the measurements, the
total number of ticks over that period is `total1 - total0`. And the idle
percentage would be `(idle1-idle0)/(total1-total0)`.

You are asking "how do you know how many ticks per second it is typically" but
as you can see, you don't need to know that.

Comment: Cool, I expected this might be the case. My problem with summing the values is that a lot of the values say that it may include ticks for other times (as in your example, ssCpuRawSystem may be wait+kernel). Is there a definitive way to know whether x includes y to prevent double-counting?

Answer (score 3):

Since *most* of the Linux distros have the 1/100 ticks, a very simple way to do it is via bash:

```
[myhost]# echo "scale=2; -1 * (`snmpget -Oqv -v2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.54.0;sleep 5` - `snmpget -Oqv -v2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.54.0` )/`snmpwalk -Oqu -v2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2 | wc -l`/5" | bc | sed 's/^\./0./' | awk '{print "CPU_IOWAIT% " $1}'

IOWAIT 0.07

[myhost]#
```

On RH/Centos and Ubuntu, it works well and precisely for 5 secs interval... Less than that, snmp does not increment the Counter32, and you get zeroes all the time.

I have done loops and compared with `iostat -c 5 100`, also generating IO with `dd`, and it worked well.

You can use any of the ssCPUraw OIDs (1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.5x from 50 to 57, if I am not wrong, in my example I have used ssCPURawWait, 54),  and the `1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2 | wc -l` is to get the number of cores...

You need to divide the "delta" of the counter / interval - in my case, 5 /  - this is basically what the script does!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has been already written by chutz, the reference to the duration of a tick can be found in `man 2 times`:

> The number of clock ticks per second can be obtained using:
>
> ```
>      sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
> ```

which is a system function to be called in C but also can be obtained by simply running `getconf CLK_TCK` in your shell. This number is a compile-time constant and *could* be changed by anyone touching the source files, but this would be a rather rare event - common Linux distros all come with the value 100.

For example:

```
$ getconf CLK_TCK
100
```

Comment: I assume this value would have to be acquired from the hardware I'm asking about over SNMP, not locally. I'll see if I can do this through the limited shell I'm given — unless it is exposed over SNMP...?

Comment: @bjeanes I don't believe it is. BTW, I looked up what method of calculation OpenNMS is using in its NetSNMP-MIB-fed graphs - it resembles the one described by chutz: it lets RRD calculate the units/timeperiod average for `ssCpuRawUser`, `ssCpuRawNice`, and `ssCpuRawSystem`, divides the respective value by the sum of `ssCpuRawUser + ssCpuRawNice + ssCpuRawSystem + ssCpuRawIdle` and multiplies by 100 to get the percentage. Another graph shows a simplistic approach by just dividing ssCpuRaw* values by 100 (blindly assuming an _SC_CLK_TCK of 100)